# Get image ratio from mobile directory

Tags: javascript, android, css, cordova

I'm testing a bit with Phonegap and Android.
At the moment I need to get the height and width of an image which isn't actual loaded.
The filestructure from phonegap is like this:
assets/
assets/www
assets/www/css
assets/www/img
assets/www/index.html

But when I try this:

```
var myImg = new Image();
myImg .src = "img/myImage.png";
alert(myImage.width + " : " + myImage.height);
```

I got nothing. The output is "0 0".
I tried every combination because I don't know on which I level I'm so I tried:

```
../img/myImage.png
www/img/myImage.png
assets/www/img/myImage.png
```

Nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume per your example code that what you mean by "isn't actually loaded" is not put into the page yet, as there would be no way to access the width and height if the image is not loaded!

The issue is that your image has not loaded by the time you request the height and width. You need to use the onload event to wait until the image loads and then ask javascript to grab the height and width. Be careful not to set the src before attaching the onload event, else you will miss cached images.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B8Ge5/

(No HTML/CSS needed)

### JS

```
var img = new Image()
  , source = 'http://i.imgur.com/XmqQuvu.jpg';

img.onload = function(){
    alert( 'Width: ' + this.width + 'Height: ' + this.height );
};

img.src = source;
```

Joshua

Comment: Thank you, that works. So I was to fast because I didn't wait for the onload and so the image wasn't available. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. An image still loads in javascript event if it has not been added to the page yet. If an image has not loaded how could it know the size? :) That is of course unless you store the size in a database and pass that data to the page. If this answer works for you, don't forget to select it as the correct answer by clicking the checkmark below the up/down vote.